# Difference between "saw" and "show"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

1)

> I **saw** her yesterday

or

> I **show** her yesterday.

2)

> Did you **saw** him the pictures?

or

> Did you **show** him the pictures?

I always goof-up using saw/show.

Answer (score 2):

*Saw* is the past of *see* - what you do with your eyes.

*Show* is the present (and base form) of a different verb, which means "cause somebody else to see" or "make available for somebody to see".

Answer (score 0):

In Your First Sentence, I saw her yesterday means you saw a person yesterday. I show her yesterday will be incorrect. 
Show means to Make a person look at a particular thing. Example - I show her them the time everyday. If you are talking about one specific case, then you would say I showed her the new watch.

Did you saw him the pictures is incorrect. Did you see the pictures is a better usage.

Did you show him the pictures is correct. Saw is used like this - I saw the boat leave the dock yesterday. The Yesterday is optional.

Comment: Why are you Capitalizing random Words in your sentences? I know it’s difficult if you’re posting from a phone (at least my phone sometimes thinks I’m starting a new sentence when I’m just trying to fix what I’ve written), but proper capitalization and punctuation is important in answers to make them as easy to understand as possible.